# Noob questions from a Sketchup user

Tags: modeling

I'm a long time user of Sketchup and I decided to finally learn Blender, but Blender is different from Sketchup in almost every possible way and I have trouble with a lot of things, so..

1. line tool, it doesn't exist in Blender, the knife tool does however, so if I want to draw a simple line between two points on a edge of a face of a box for example (but **not** at the middle points of the face) and to be precise, how am I supposed to do that?

A way to do that would be the loop tool, but that also creates unnecessary divisions on other faces which I don't want.

2. Is there a curvy line tool? Say that I want to draw a dog house entrance and the upper side of the door has to be curved, do I just draw a regular blocky shape and then subdivide the upper part a bunch of times and move the vertices up or is there a different easier way? In Sketchup you'd just draw a box shape and curvy line at the top, extrude it to the inside of the dog house and it would instantly create a hole/door, done, not even 5 seconds of work.
3. Textures, my biggest issue. In Sketchup you simply choose a texture, click on a face and done, again less than 5 seconds of work. Do I have to do the UV unwrapping stuff in Blender or can I also paint face by face if I want to? (for simpler objects) Also, if I want to create a long wall like object and put textures on it, how do I do that so that the textures repeat seamlessly?

I only know how to create subdivision a bunch of times and then make each face use the same part of the UV texture, but in Sketchup you just paint a wall and it automatically repeats the texture across the wall and you can easily make the texture larger or smaller.

4. Offset tool, how does it work? In Sketchup you choose a face and that just set how much you want, I suppose that Blender does the same thing, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: hi, welcome. This site's policies do not allow multiple questions per post, please split them to get proper answers...

Comment: This may be of help https://www.blendermarket.com/products/snap-utilities Also you never "apply textures to faces", you only apply materials.